# Frequent updates by TeX Live Utility

Tags: texlive-2017

I'm using the *TeX Live Utility* (2017) on a Mac (High Sierra) to keep my TeX/LaTeX/.. distribution up to date, but I'm bewildered by the number of updates it reports and applies. (I'm using the http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet mirror.)

**Every day at least a page (20-30) of new packages are reported as needing updates**, so every day I do so. (This is hyperbole: the average is closer to 15.)

Is this usual? Are there really such a vast number of bugs in this system? Presumably, most of the packages that require updates, are new ones for arcane purposes (e.g. the standard format for the *Journal of Bespoke Shoe Makers & Cobblers* with an embedded *Mathematica* scripting engine) that aren't crucial in my line of work (maths), so is there a stable "mainstream, vanilla core" that requires fewer updates? (Apologies to the developers of arcane packages: while I, personally, don’t have a use for many packages, that doesn’t mean they aren’t important.)

Any information about how frequently I should be expecting updates, or whether this endless chatter by *TeX Live Utility* indicates some sort of viral infection, would be greatly appreciated.

**Notes & Corrections**
- 20-30 new packages per day might have been hyperbole. Still, when I checked today I had 24 packages awaiting installation, so as hyperbole goes it was modest. Perhaps 15-20 updates per day would be more accurate.
- Secondly, some people have suggested that my installation must be flawed, but I can’t see how: I’m using the vanilla Mac installer, so my experience is presumably common. Should I delete lualatex and the Bulgarian bibtex packages? Does this cause dependency issues with third party software?

Comment: Every day 30–40 updates? That occasionally happens but certainly not every day. Note that TeX Live comes with a huge number of packages and they occasionally needto be updated as other packages change.

Comment: I use a lot LaTeX and I update TeXlive maybe every 2 weeks. So, disable the automatic updates and be happy.

Comment: CTAN announcements (https://ctan.org/ctan-ann) will tell you which packages have been added, fixed, or enhanced. Subscribe, and then you’ll know when there are updates that interest you and when the updates are not relevant to your work.

Comment: Why do you think that packages that require an update are "bug-ridden"? The update can also be an improvement and bring new features.

Comment: Do you need to update? If not, don't if you don't want to. There's no particular virtue in updating every day or, indeed, at all, unless you run into a bug or need something new.

Comment: @Thérèse It is possible for a developer to update a package on CTAN, but not issue an announcement. I do that, when the update is some obscure internal change that will not affect users. As for the original question: I do not see that many updates on a regular basis, using tlmgr.

Comment: many people never update by tlmgr and just update when they get a new texlive the following year. In a collection of programs separately maintained by thousands of different authors, it's not at all surprising that you get a few updates a week, there is no need to insult the authors of the packages that are being updated by calling the packages bug-ridden.

Answer (score 3):

Your set-up must have something wrong, because it simply isn't the case that 20-30 packages get updated each day on CTAN, on average.

Comment: No empirical data, but my impression is 5-10 updates per day are more realistic.

Comment: @samcarter You are probably right. I recall reading somewhere about 100 updates per month, and there are no doubt more frantic periods (when one gets close to TeXLive deadline for inclusion in next year's edition).